# Parse a json file

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a json into my list view. I don't no what is the problem? but i got an exception telling me that Names must be Strings and must be unique within an object.

Here is my code:

```
try {

            jsonString =  "{[{\"url\":\"www.200Chess.com\",\"price\":\"Free\",\"name\":\"200 Chess Opening\"},{\"url\":\"www.midgame.com\",\"price\":\"10$\",\"name\":\"Mid Game TacHcs\"},{\"url\":\"www.303checkmate.com\",\"price\":\"20$\",\"name\":\"303 Checkmate puzzles\"},{\"url\":\"www.303winning.com\",\"price\":\"30$\",\"name\":\"303 Winning Strategies\"},{\"url\":\"www.bibby.com\",\"price\":\"10$\",\"name\":\"Bobby Fusher Teaches Chess\"}]}";

            json= new JSONObject(jsonString);

            JSONArray jsonBook = json.getJSONArray("");

            for (int i=0; i<jsonBook.length();i++){

                Book book =new Book();

                JSONObject jsonAttributes = jsonBook.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("");

                Log.i("ListBooks", jsonAttributes.toString());

                book.name = jsonAttributes.getString(KEY_NAME);

                Log.i("ListBooks", book.name);

                book.price = jsonAttributes.getString(KEY_PRICE);

                book.url = jsonAttributes.getString(KEY_URL);

                books.add(book);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

I got this exception:

```
06-05 21:59:42.283: W/System.err(541): org.json.JSONException: Names must be strings, but [{"url":"www.200Chess.com","name":"200 Chess Opening","price":"Free"},{"url":"www.midgame.com","name":"Mid Game TacHcs","price":"10$"},{"url":"www.303checkmate.com","name":"303 Checkmate puzzles","price":"20$"},{"url":"www.303winning.com","name":"303 Winning Strategies","price":"30$"},{"url":"www.bibby.com","name":"Bobby Fusher Teaches Chess","price":"10$"}] is of type org.json.JSONArray at character 361 of {[{"url":"www.200Chess.com","price":"Free","name":"200 Chess Opening"},{"url":"www.midgame.com","price":"10$","name":"Mid Game TacHcs"},{"url":"www.303checkmate.com","price":"20$","name":"303 Checkmate puzzles"},{"url":"www.303winning.com","price":"30$","name":"303 Winning Strategies"},{"url":"www.bibby.com","price":"10$","name":"Bobby Fusher Teaches Chess"}]}
06-05 21:59:42.283: W/System.err(541):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:363)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:96)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at tn.haythem.learnchess.ListBooks.getBooks(ListBooks.java:157)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at tn.haythem.learnchess.ListBooks.onCreate(ListBooks.java:52)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-05 21:59:42.293: W/System.err(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-05 21:59:42.303: W/System.err(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-05 21:59:42.303: W/System.err(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-05 21:59:42.303: W/System.err(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-05 21:59:42.313: W/System.err(541):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 21:59:42.313: W/System.err(541):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-05 21:59:42.313: W/System.err(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-05 21:59:42.313: W/System.err(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 21:59:42.313: W/System.err(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-05 21:59:42.313: W/System.err(541):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-05 21:59:42.313: W/System.err(541):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-05 21:59:42.323: W/System.err(541):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can any body please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array in the JSON object has no name, which is not valid, e.g. it should start like this:

```
"{\"thearrayname\":[{\"url\":\"www.200Chess.com\",\" ...
```

or remove the outer `{` and `}` and parse it as a JSONArray directly e.g.:

```
[{\"url\":\"www.200Chess.com\",\" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your JSON with the format shown below. It is precisely because your JSON file structure is incorrect that you are unable to parse it properly.

Correct format:

```
{
    "an": [
        {
            "url": "www.200Chess.com",
            "price": "Free",
            "name": "200ChessOpening"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting the JSON into [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) for a nice gui syntax checker